# How to call app Model in initializers with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in Ruby on Rails and i am using Ruby version 2.1.0 and Rails 4.0.2

My Query is:-

I want to call **Model** in **initializers**.

my **Model** file is **setting.rb** and **Model** name **Setting**. its location is **app/model** directory.

I want to call **Setting Model** in **initializers** file **paypal.rb**.

**paypal.rb** location is **config/initializers/paypal.rb**.

Please help how to call **Model** in **initializers** in **Ruby on Rails**.

Comment: Please share the code you have written, and tell us the error that you are getting when you try.

Comment: Please share your code like @TarynEast said - also, what happens if you try to add `require models/setting` at the top of your `paypal.rb` file?

Answer (score 23):

Do you want to make sure all other initializers have run before running this one? If so you could do this:

```
# config/initializers/paypal.rb
Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
  paypal_settings = Setting.find_by(name: "paypal")
  # do something with paypal settings...
end
```

Comment: I'm not OP, but I ran into the same issue, and I get a the following bug (in my case it's `User` instead of `Setting`):   

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `attr_accessible' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError).   

I'm going to investigate whether it has to deal with a missing database connection, but otherwise do you have any other insight?

Comment: Never mind what I said above, I fixed my issue with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437830/undefined-method-attr-accessible

Answer (score 3):

To get around that problem I did this:

1. First I check if the table exists.
2. Then I check if my record exists.
3. Otherwise I just set a default value.

It's kind of a hack but it works for my use case.

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? :settings # check if table exists
  if Setting.first.present? # check if first record has been seeded
    NUMBERS = Setting.first.my_numbers.split(",")
  else
    NUMBERS = '987654321'
  end
else
  NUMBERS = '123456789'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned solutions would still fail on `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:bootstrap` if the database does not exist. In my case the build was getting failed on circleCI.

Following solution worked out for me properly.

```rb
# /app/config/initializers/settings.rb
db_loaded = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection(&:active?) rescue false

if db_loaded && Setting.table_exists?
// business logic
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In the rails, wherever you are, you can interact with Models. 
Like

```
Setting.method_name()
```

Inside the rails application, you can create your own new folder(expect default directories created by rails new command) and can interact with Model methods.

Comment: If you are migrating the project, initializers run before migration. In this case, the table won't exist.