# How to access model in environment configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a multi-tenant application where each tenants information is stores in the database.

I have some variables in the environment configs (development.rb, production.rb) which I want to populate with data from the DB.

Trying to call the model doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to call a model in the application initializer?

**Edit:**

Here is the code:

```
# production.rb
Rails.application.configure do {
  config.custom_variable = MyModel.myattribute
}
```

This returns a `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` error

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Trying to access a model gives a `undefined local variable or method` error

Comment: Yeah, this little amount of info, it doesn't help much. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Added code to question

Comment: What if you called `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection!` there?

Comment: `method_missing': undefined method 'establish_connection!' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Comment: Remember that your database connection settings are also part of the environment configuration. So you want to read from the db when its connections have not been setup yet. It might be better to read the configuration from text files.

Comment: refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680047/how-to-call-app-model-in-initializers-with-ruby-on-rails*emphasized text*)

Answer (score 1):

Initializers run before ActiveRecord is loaded, so you'll need to wait for ActiveRecord before accessing it.

Wrapping your code in an `ActiveSupport#on_load` block should work.

```
# production.rb
Rails.application.configure do {
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
     config.custom_variable = MyModel.myattribute
  end
}
```

Comment: I get a `undefined local variable or method 'config' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NameError)`

Comment: Try `.configure do |config|` and take out the curly braces. That was based on your earlier code.